# Connect to MS access database using PyQt5

Tags: python, ms-access, pyqt5

I'm trying to connect to a MS access database using the following code:

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QODBC")
db.setDatabaseName(
        "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:\\database.accdb")
if db.open(): print("opened")
```

I have office 2019 installed.
I cannot figure out what is wrong in the connection string or the driver.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that this problem happened because I have a 64-bit of python and a 32-bit of access database engine driver.

After installing the 64-bit access database engine driver, I managed to get it work.